# Classic ASP: Check if headers are sent to the client

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, web-deployment-project

Can we tell if HTTP headers are already sent to the browser, in classic ASP?

In PHP, we can use headers_sent() for this.

Using IIS7

Comment: I'm sad that nobody has really answered this question after all this time.  I'd like to be able to test if any headers have been sent, before, y'know, sending some headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the Request or Response Objects?  That's the only thing I can think of that would show the header information.

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_request.asp

Comment: Yes, I checked the response object and some others, nothing I can see. There may be a chance with the server variables or something..

Comment: Are you looking for something specific?

Comment: No, just a method, a server variable or something to check if the headers are sent, using pure asp classic -)

Answer (score -1):

use this example/tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_servervariables.asp

ALL_HTTP -- Returns all HTTP headers sent by the client. Always prefixed with HTTP_ and capitalized

Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables ("ALL_HTTP"))

Comment: The question is about whether *response* headers have been sent by the server to the client.